# Is there a way to get the current system volume in a Cordova/Ionic3 Project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am making an Hybrid app that plays some audios using Web audio API and I want to show a warning when the device volume is too high.

There are a couple of Cordova plugins that set the volumen to a desired value but none of them expose a method for get the current volume (or at least I wasn't able to find those).

Is there a way to get the current system volume?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin should be for you:

- [cordova-volume](https://github.com/g-w/cordova-volume)

It supports both Android and iOS. It is a little bit that it is no longer updated so I'm not sure that it works also in the last platform versions.